# for how long tablespace is in read only

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to find a usefull query that can show me if tablespace is in read only state more than 3 hours.

I uses the next query to check if it is in read only state  :

```
select tablespace_name,status from dba_tablespaces
```

In what table I can check for how long it is in read only ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Altering a tablespace to make it read-only should be a controlled activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored not in dba_tablespaces but in v$datafile.

You can use this SQL-query to get needed information (all datafiles in read only state more than 3 hours). 1/8 is 3 hours (24/8).

```
SELECT t.name, d.file#, d.name, d.status, d.offline_change#, d.last_time
FROM v$datafile d, v$tablespace t
WHERE t.ts# = d.ts# AND last_time IS NOT NULL AND last_time<SYSDATE-1/8;
```

Comment: I need to check also the the column enabled  get the value read only dont I ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select h.TABLESPACE_NAME,t.status ,checkpoint_change#,to_char(checkpoint_time,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')chkpt_time
from v$datafile_header h ,  dba_tablespaces t
where h.TABLESPACE_NAME = t.TABLESPACE_NAME 
and t.status ='READ ONLY'
and checkpoint_time <sysdate-3/24
```